# I'm trying to write a for loop but one of the values won't update. R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm just trying to write a simple for loops so I can see how much the person would owe after each consecutive year. It ends up printing the statement with only the n value ever  changed. The A stays the same as the first time.

```
for (n in 1:15){
  A <-  5000 * (1+ .115/100) ^n
  sprintf("%.2f owed after %.f years", A, n) 
 }
```

I have no clue what to do to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Just add a `print` :  "print(sprintf("%.2f owed after %.f years", A, n) )". Otherwise, since it is inside a for loop, `sprintf` will not print to the console.

Comment: @lbusett it worked thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a print statement-

```
   for (n in 1:15){
   A <-  5000 * (1+ .115/100) ^n
   print(sprintf("%.2f owed after %.f years", A, n)) 
   }
```